No icons on Talend Open Studio Interface on linux
I have just installed the latest Talend Open Studio in Ubuntu linux and no icons are showing in the interface, just red squares like in the image:

Someone know how to fix it? I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, gnome 42.9, java openjdk 17.
Do I need to install something else like a library or something?
